# Detecting wifi list Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, package, wifi

Im working on a Flutter app and want to get list of wifi inside the app , Want this app just for android .
I am using this package : https://pub.dev/packages/wifi
Does any one has any example or idea about how to use Properties and Method of this package?
Thanks

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/alternadom/WiFiFlutter

Answer (score 1):

please use this package https://pub.dev/packages/android_wifi_info 
I have tested it with real device Samsung Galaxy A7, it's work fine

step 1, download the package include example. https://github.com/smaho-engineering/android_wifi_info

step 2 remark the following two return line in android_wifi_info.dart, since it's cause error

```
  /// TODO: Android Q feature, not added to the API in Java yet.
  static Future<int> get rxLinkSpeedMbps {
    //return _channel.invokeMethod('rxLinkSpeedMbps');
  }

static Future<int> get txLinkSpeedMbps {
    //return _channel.invokeMethod('txLinkSpeedMbps');
  }
```

step 3 run this example, in real device, ssid show data correctly

[image]